# Paypal recurring payment gateway modify subscription

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway

I am using **Paypal recurring payment gateway** to make a subscription of certain amount per month using PHP in Yii.

i dont have any Yii pre built extension so i created my own extension for Paypal recurring payment gateway and its working great.

I am doing this by createrecurringprofile() function of paypal with Express checkout API.

On first sign up, user needs to select one subscription package from 4 packages and after login he/she can update his subscription.

My problem is that if a user have signup with 24$ amount with gold subscription (name of package) package. And now he/she wants to upgrade his package with platinum package after only 10 days.

so how to do this thing with paypal as user already subscribed one payment for 24$ per month.

I need to know exact process to do this whether i have to cancel old subscription and make one new one. or can i modify that old subscription name and amount to be deduct per month.

Thanks in advance !!!